# VB.NET Convert string to a DirectoryInfo

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to change the file path my program uses to collect data and am using the `FolderBrowserDialog` to find it.

```
Dim folder As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
folder.SelectedPath = ("UserDatabases/")

If folder.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK And folder.SelectedPath IsNot Nothing Then
    di = folder.SelectedPath()
End If
```

I keep getting the following error under the `di= folder.SelectedPath()` line

> value of type string cannot be converted to System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just assign a new path to your existing `DirectoryInfo` instance, you instead have to create a new one:

```
di = New DirectoryInfo(folder.SelectedPath)
```